# How can I put the include text to concatinate with text element in SmartForms (ABAP)?

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

In SmartForms, I currently have a format like this:

```
Address: 
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

"Address: " is in the text element and the address content is in the include text with text name, text object, text ID, and language. However, I would like to show like this:

```
Address: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
```

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Comment: What is your Smart Form "code"? What are the parameters relative to the address configuration?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can achieve that by

1. Create Local variable of char or string within the smartforms
2. Create a local code block within the smartform
3. Obtain the text via Function Module READ_TEXT similar to how you achieve it in text element with text name, text id, and all. Put this in the code block as I mentioned in step 2.
4. After the Function Module call, concatenate the result of the text (or the text element as you call it) to "Address" and assign it to the local variable as I mentioned in step 1
5. Put the local variable of step 1 to the part of the smartforms, instead of the text element.

Answer (score 0):

Then you can go to smartforms initialization and put in your read_text or the variable you are receiving from the input interfaces

This way you can concatenate using.

Algo try increasing the size of the line in the smarforms that is receiving this information

Answer (score 0):

In the include text node you can set the option "Start" under "General Attributes" to "Append directly". This negates the forced paragraph on every new text element. This works on every text node in smartforms
[image]